# How to upload more than one file with form data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use more than one file uploader along with text fields? When I remove the file uploader it's working. How can I add my files?

```html
<form id="uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" /><br /> This is Single File
  <input type="file" id="fileInput1" multiple /><br /> Multipul File
  <b>Eneter Id </b> <input type="text" id="Id" /><br />
  <b>Name</b> <input type="text" id="Name" /><br />
  <input type="button" id="fileButton" value="Upload Files" /><br />
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:50895/CsgFiles/";

  $("#fileButton").click(function(e) {
    debugger

    var fileform = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var files = fileform.files;
    var fileform1 = document.getElementById('fileInput1');
    var files1 = fileform1.files;
    var abc = {
      Id: $("#Id").val().trim(),
      Name: $("#Name").val().trim(),
      File2: files,
      File1: files1,
    }

    var data = new FormData(); //From Here Please Help me How can i use
    data.append('File2', files)

    $.ajax({
      url: apiBaseUrl + 'saveFiles',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
    }).done(function(data) {
      debugger
    }).fail(function(e) {
      debugger;
    });
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're uploading all the content from the controls of the `form` then the simplest way to build the FormData object is to provide the reference of the `form` to the constructor, then all the `append()` logic is done for you.

Also note that when dealing with forms you should hook to the `submit` event of the form itself, not the click of the submit button.

Finally, you need to include `contentType: false` on the `$.ajax` call too, so that jQuery sets the correct headers.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  var apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:50895/CsgFiles/";

  $("#uploader").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
      url: apiBaseUrl + 'saveFiles',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
    }).done(function(data) {
      debugger;
      console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(e) {
      debugger;
    });
  });
});
```

I'd also suggest using a relative path for the call, eg: `var apiBaseUrl = "/CsgFiles/";`. This way the code will still work when moving between local/dev/live environments. It also removes the possibility of any cross-domain accidents using different protocols.

Comment: Data is not Binding at server side Getting Null Value

Comment: That depends on your server side code being configured correctly. I'd suggest starting a new question about it.